# How to assign default value of the model based on the value of ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, design-patterns

I have the `Account` model were I store information about preferred units.
However I also want to allow user to change the units for particular exercise which by default should be `Account.units`.

Here are my models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    """Model to store user's data and preferences."""
    UNIT_CHOICES = [
        ('metric', 'Metric'),
        ('imperial', 'Imperial')
    ]

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    units = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=UNIT_CHOICES, default=UNIT_CHOICES[0], null=False, blank=False)
    weight_metric = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    height_metric = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    weight_imperial = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    height_imperial = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.email
```

```
class CustomExercise(models.Model):
    UNIT_CHOICES = [
        ('metric', 'Metric'),
        ('imperial', 'Imperial')
    ]

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    preferred_units = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=UNIT_CHOICES, default=owner.units, null=False, blank=False) # <- throws an error that "ForeignKey doesn't have units attribute."
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

    measure_time = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    measure_distance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    measure_weight = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    measure_reps = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner}:{self.name}'
```

As posted in code sample I tried to get that default value from ForeignKey, which not unexpectedly did not work out.
So my question is: what is the correct solution to implement this kind of feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend storing duplicate values accross multiple models. You can easily access that value through a property method:

```
class CustomExercise(models.Model):
   ... # remove preferred_units field from model
   @property
   def preferred_units(self):
      return self.owner.unit
```

Although you can not use it in queryset directly, still you can annotate the 'owner__unit' field in queryset or filter by it:

```
q = CustomExcercise.objects.annotate(preferred_units=F('owner__unit')).filter(preferred_units = 'kg')

q.values()
```

Displaying the value in Adminsite:

```
class CustomExerciseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (..., 'preferred_units')
    readonly_fields = ['preferred_units']
```

Comment: I got an Attribute error, `property 'preferred_units' of 'CustomExercise' object has no setter` after trying to save the new Exercise via Django Admin Panel.

Comment: did you remove the model field from CustomExercise?

Comment: yes I did, and run migrations afterwards.

Comment: Can you add the full error stacktrace please?

Comment: I found an issue it was colliding with the suggestion from the other answer. Works perfectly now, thank you kindly =)

Answer (score 2):

Two ways come to mind: overriding the model's `save` method or by using a `pre_save` signal. I would try the first one and if it doesn't work then the second one. The reason is that signals are notoriously difficult to debug so if you have alternatives you should always leave them as a last resort.

Ok so, I think this should work:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.preferred_units = self.owner.units
        super(CustomExercise, self).save(*args, **kwargs
```

Otherwise:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=CustomExercise)
def assign_unit(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.preferred_units = instance.owner.units
```

The convention is to store your signals in `signals.py` in your app. Make sure to "activate" them from `apps.py` or they won't work. Here [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/).

Comment: the problem with the `save` method is that the User would have to first create the Exercise and only then go back and change the units which I would love to avoid.

Comment: Signal solution looks fine although I cannot debug it for now since I only operate in Django Admin panel and I need to pick Account assigned to Exercise manually...